# How to delete my question if an answer already given? (Because I found I made a mistake somewhere else)

Tags: discussion

How to delete my question if an answer already given?
(Because I found I made a mistake somewhere else)

Say I asked "Error: code using algorithm-A went crash".
And later I found it is not code's fault, but algorithm-A's fault.

Answer (score 7):

Don't delete it, but post an answer instead. Your question/answer might be useful to other people who run into a the same problem. The existing answer might be useful to people with similar problems.

Comment: If it's the algorithm and not the implementation, this seems like a candidate for closing (a la "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."; it might be helpful to edit the question so that it matches up with the answer, too.  E.g., instead of "why doesn't this code work?", make the question "this code is a correct implementation of the algorithm, but why doesn't this algorithm produce the result I expect?"  That said, +1 for [encouraging users to answer rather than delete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203771/225437).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It sounds like this stands a much better chance of being more useful than a typo/missing semicolon question. I agree that editing the question might be called for in this kind of case.

Comment: I definitely agree this is more likely to be useful, but if the question is phrased as "what's wrong with this code", then it's less likely to be found by those to whom it would be useful.  The people who'd find it would those trying to implement the same algorithm (I suppose they could take the implementation from the question, but they should be hesitant to if the question suggests that it's incorrect).  That's why I suggested editing the question, too.

Answer (score 2):

Post an answer if you got one, it may help someone in the future but ...

if it was a typo or something like that and you don't think it will help any future visitors or if it qualifies for one of the close reasons than vote to close and direct others to do so.

If the question receives 5 close votes than it will be closed, then other trusted users may decide to delete it in the end.

note:

If someone has answered your question and received upvotes then in a case your question gets deleted they will lose that rep so please make sure your question is really not going to help any future visitors when it comes to deletion.