# Encourage OP to post a self-answer when they vote to delete their question

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, self-answer, self-delete

There are times when a person has a problem, searches, does not find a solution and proceeds to post a question somewhere on the Stack Exchange network, only to soon after figure out what the answer was.

It would appear that many times, such questions are simply deleted by the OP. One possible example might be [this question just now on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/582872/regex-counting-spaces-tabs-followed-by-non-whitespace).

If the OP had trouble figuring something out, it stands to reason that others might too.

Hence, I think **users should be encouraged somehow to post a self-answer rather than delete their own, unanswered question** if they are deleting the question because they figured out what the answer was.

There are many ways that this could be done, including in a popup triggered by clicking "delete".

Comment: Perhaps people do so out of embarrassment  - *"I can't believe I didn't know this, it's so obvious now I think about it"*. They may not want to be associated with it. Perhaps they could be able to disassociate themselves from the question instead / as well? (Actually, that's getting quite a convoluted workflow for deleting a post, so perhaps not)

Comment: @JonW Well, that's [another issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said)

Comment: It's funny that you brought this up because I just encountered [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481752/android-null-pointer-exception-on-setadapter#comment34199799_22481752) before reading this post. I think the first step is for us more experienced users to suggest this to the OP so they understand it is an option.

Comment: @codeMagic That's pretty hard for lots of people once the post has been deleted. I personally don't have the rep required to view deleted posts on any site (as far as I am aware) except on Amateur Radio (where I get that privilege from being a moderator on the site).

Comment: @MichaelMrozek JonW's idea could be implemented in a fairly straight-forward manner by e.g. asking the user with a popup "you choose to delete; would you perhaps rather answer your own question, or disassociate it from your account?". Doesn't have to be that convoluted, although that is straying from the intent of this post.

Comment: "Once the post is deleted", right, but I'm talking about us being proactive. You can leave comments which is all that takes. I'm not saying implementing something as you are suggesting would be good *or* bad. I'm just saying that the first step is for us to leave the comment *before* the post is deleted when possible. No, this won't help once they have deleted but when we see this happen as we are helping someone then we should comment with the suggestion. That was all I was saying.

Comment: @codeMagic Unfortunately, many times that is not possible. The particular example post lived on the site for a few minutes before it was deleted by the OP. Not much time to post "if you figure this out, please do leave a self-answer", let alone write up a full answer.

Comment: I've also seen this go horribly wrong. Pretty recently I suggested that a new user self-answer and the 'answer' they wrote was poor and it got downvoted. So not sure that I feel either way about this.

Comment: I like the idea, but only if the question has a positive score.

Answer (score 3):

Prompting users to contribute the solutions they found instead of just deleting the questions seems valuable in two ways: other people with this problem will find an answer, and more participation can lead to more engagement from that user (supposition, not science).  But we want to avoid blow-back where the user writes an answer, it's not well-received, and now that user resents the waste of time and is *less* likely to return.  So we probably want to restrict when we offer this option:

- The question should have a good score; we want to do this for *well-asked* questions.  What's "good"?  I propose a score of 3, which is also the threshold where deletions don't always take rep away.
- The question should have been on the site for some time.  People sometimes ask a question, realize within a few minutes that it wasn't a good question, and delete it.  We shouldn't bug people for an answer in that case; let the user withdraw gracefully.  How long?  I'm not sure; maybe two days like for protection and community deletion?
- The question should be open.  (Duh, but the code should do the check to avoid bad UX from "you asked me to answer but I can't!".)

Comment: Two days is also the limit for starting a bounty on a question, so that seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

As I discussed [in this post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/should-an-answer-by-the-questioner-be-held-to-a-different-standard), when someone finds a solution to their own problem it is often not something that would be a valuable answer to others. Thus, encouraging people to report back with their solutions would possibly be encouraging sub-par answers.